# Filter a list from the txt file under specific conditions

Tags: python-3.x, list, txt

I need to filter a txt file on specific words. Words that end with 'd', that are less than 10 letters and words that have duplicate letters should be filtered out from the txt file. Then they should be returned as a list of words and number of words as a pair. So far I have this

```
exclude = 'd'
f = open('nameofthefile.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: What have you tried? You have not even read the text.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you haven't yet, you need to make an honest attempt at solving the problem yourself before asking here. If you've tried something already that didn't work, share that as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask a specific question about the problem you ran into.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I made.

I'm not sure I understood everything you said but here is what I made:

`nameofthefile.txt`:

```
abcd
abcdefghijk
0123456789d
aabbccdd
```

`main.py:`

```py
def filtering(filename: str):
    f = open(filename,'r').read().split("\n")
    lst = []
    for e in f: # For elements in file
        if e[-1] == "d" and len(e) < 10 and sorted([*set(e)]) == sorted(e):
            lst += [e]
    return lst
    
print(filtering('nameofthefile.txt')) # ["abcd"]
```

You can refractor it like:

```py
def filtering(filename: str):
    f = open(filename,'r').read().split("\n")
    return [e for e in f if e[-1] == "d" and len(e) < 10 and sorted([*set(e)]) == sorted(e)]
    
print(filtering('nameofthefile.txt')) # ["abcd"]
```

If the last letter is d:

```py
e[-1] == 'd'
```

If the word is less than 10 letters:

```py
len(e) < 10
```

If the word doesn't have duplicate letters

```py
sorted([*set(e)]) == sorted(e)
```